# Kotlin Data class Unresolved reference error when access to property

Tags: kotlin, getter, data-class

I am new with Kotlin and maybe it is a basic question, I have to access the properties from a data class, this is the data class:

```
data class Success(
  val bugs: Int,
  val fixed: Int,
) : Result
```

`Result` is an interface and the argument that I get in my function is of the type `Result`.

What I am trying to do is just trying to access the value from bugs and fixed, such as:

```
 fun process(data: Result) : String {
    data.bugs
    return ""
  }
```

And I am getting the next error:

```
Unresolved reference: bugs
```

Any ideas? As far as I know val generates `getters` to access the property, but in the other way bug is a private variable. I am not sure how can I access this property, I also used `getBugs` and got the same error message:

```
Unresolved reference: getBugs
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it is not the cause of the issue

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that my data Class is inside an interface and the method its returning the interface

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Result is apparently an empty interface or one that at least doesn’t define a `bugs` property. In the context of this function, all you have is a Result, not a Success, so you can’t access things that are specific to the Success class because as far as the function is concerned, it could be dealing with some other Result implementation that doesn’t have a bugs property.

Answer (score 0):

`bugs` id defined on `Success`, not `Result`. You either need to use `Success` in the function

```kotlin
fun process(data: Success) : String {
    data.bugs
    return ""
}
```

or check the type

```kotlin
fun process(data: Result) : String {
    when (data) {
        is Success -> {
            data.bugs
            return ""
        }
        else -> TODO("Handle the other cases")
    }
}
```